# How to run the blackberry application in Titanium appcelerator in blackberry simulator

Tags: titanium-mobile, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am new to Titanium appcelerator.I instll the Titanium studio and blackberry sdk in the Titanium.And I download the Blackberry simulator.I create the new project in Titanium studio with deployment target as BlackBerry.It is created successfully.

But my question is:

How to establish the connection between the BlackBerry simulator and new project?

Answer (score 0):

When you go through [this post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/blackberry/getting-started-beta-preview) in ***developer.appcelerator***, first portions are describing all the steps to setup development environment and create a project. Look at following sub-heads of post,

(A) Running the Simulator

(B) Installing To Device

Hope it helped you